# Core Data: NSPredicate with object made of entity object

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nspredicate

For example:

There is a `NSDateComponents *dueDate` (Transformable) property of `Task *` entity. And there is intend of fetching all objects that have `NSDate *` value of `dueDate` less than `[NSDate date]`. `NSDateComponents` object is created of calendar units constant `NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit`.

`[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"dueDate < %@", [NSDate date]]` is type mismatch. How to create `NSDate` object from `dueDate` before equation?

Or is there a better way to compare `NSDateComponents`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the best solution.

Firstly i wrote a category:

```
@implementation NSDateComponents (SSDateComponent)

- (NSComparisonResult)compare:(NSDateComponents *)anotherDateComponents {
    return [[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:self] compare:[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:anotherDateComponents]];
}
```

Then i hope I can use <,>,== in predicate format. So I made `NSDateComponents *` from current date (which is also better for me) and my predicate looks like:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"dueDate < %@", dateComponents];
```

I was wondering if this could work because of Transformable type of `dueDate` in Core Data but it seems it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

The predicate should be like this:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ < %@", [dueDate date], [NSDate date]]
```

But if you only wish to compare dates, outside a predicate, you could just compare them like this:

```
if ([[dueDate date] compare:[NSDate date]] == NSOrderedAscending){
         //Then dueDate is earlier than [NSDate date], 
}
```

You can use `NSOrderedSame and NSOrderedDescending` too

Comment: I did not try, but I believe `NSDateComponents * < NSDate *` will not work.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I thought it was an NSDate, not an NSDate component. I am editing my answer.